# How can I solve "Using filesort" for this SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-optimization

There is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `deal_keyword` (
  `deal_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `keyword_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `area_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`deal_id`,`keyword_id`),
  KEY `area_id` (`area_id`,`keyword_id`,`deal_id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

And input some records for test:

```
insert into deal_keyword values(1,2,3);
insert into deal_keyword values(2,2,3);
insert into deal_keyword values(3,2,3);
insert into deal_keyword values(4,1,3);
insert into deal_keyword values(5,1,3);
insert into deal_keyword values(6,1,3);
insert into deal_keyword values(7,3,3);
insert into deal_keyword values(8,3,3);
```

When I run this SQL:

```
explain select * from `deal_keyword` where `area_id`=3 && `keyword_id` in(1,3) order by `deal_id`;

+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------+
| table        | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                    |
+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------+
| deal_keyword | range | area_id       | area_id |       8 | NULL |    4 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort |
+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------+
```

How can I solve "Using filesort" for this SQL?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Try putting an individual index on `deal_id`. You're using it by itself in the `order by` clause, and since it's the last member of a multi-field composite key, the `area_id` index can't be used for sort lookups.

Comment: Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/order-by-optimization.html ?

Comment: @marc-b thanks,if I create a index for this SQL,how can I do? (this is the MYISAM table,so I think an individual index on deal_id doesn't help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a composite index on `(area_id, deal_id, keyword_id)` (in this order)

Note that if you had additional columns in you table, index scan would not necessarily be better than a filesort for an `ORDER BY` without a `LIMIT`, since traversing the index requires table lookups which imply random seeks and are not efficient.

Comment: Perfect!I really want to know why `(area_id, deal_id, keyword_id)` not filesort but `(area_id,keyword_id,deal_id)` can,what is the difference between these two indexes?

Comment: @Zenoto: the first one preserves the order on `deal_id` within a given  `area_id`, the second one does not.